# Re sizing a Column according to its content in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying  to re-size the content presenter which is in 4th column according to its content when we re sizing the window. But its not behaving as the way I wanted. Can you guys help me out of this problem.

```
 <Grid Name="PART_grid1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Path Data="M74,37L0,37 0,0 74,0z"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill"  Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0" StartPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF9F9F9" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD7D7D7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                            <Path Data="F1M0,37L1,37 1,0 0,0z" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Fill="#FF7D7D7D" />
                            <Path Data="F1M0,37L1,37 1,0 0,0z" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Fill="White"/>


                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                                <!--Image-->
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Column="4" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Auto` in column definition:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
```

It will auto-fit to the content. It should be in the column definitions of your main grid. At the moment your value is `5` so it's pretty narrow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion PiotrWolkowski !!